# Find using PHP how usefull a document to me using search keywords i have

Tags: php, search

(Please read patiently)

I am developing a application which searches for html documents based on keywords passed like : `I want to buy a watch` OR `A watch for sale` or etc. I have large list of html documents which contain these keywords but the problem I am currently facing is that I want to fetch only those docs who match best with the keywords. Suppose I am trying to find a post about selling a watch and tried with keyword : *sell a watch* this should bring the most relevant post which is actually selling a watch **not with just contains selling word and watch word**

You could ask what I have done so far : well I have done searching the documents with a simple PHP string search and this is doing just what I don't want to. I like to have natural search, Any third party API or Any idea could help a lot.

Note : I don't have the documents saved in the DB I am just pulling them up from Internet to my code and finding with keyword if they are relevant.

Thanks

Comment: for those who downvote please please add comments as this help me refine my experience with stackoverflow.

Comment: I haven't dv'ed but the reason is that asking for tool, API and this kind of stuff is not suitable for SO.

Comment: @PLB I am not getting why Asking for API is not good, I have googled it but din't found any so i just asked the community.

Comment: Because it violates SO rules. Also answers to these kind of questions are _incomplete_, _opinion based_ and outdate really fast.

Answer (score 2):

Zend_Search_Lucene might help you. http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.search.lucene.html

If you have the possibility to install a search engine on your server I would recommend [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) or [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/).

You coul also use some 3rd party search SAAS like (in no particular order):

http://www.indexden.com/

http://www.searchify.com/

http://www.found.no/

http://websolr.com/

https://swiftype.com/

https://searchbox.io/

http://www.houndsleuth.com/

http://www.bonsai.io/home

Comment: Or the Lucene project more generally: http://lucene.apache.org

Comment: Hmm Thanks for these useful resources i will take a look.